# Java to play audio file through the commandline

Tags: java, command-line, playback, javasound

I would like to play a sound file using java through the command line.

so far I have succeded at listing the contents of a directory, but cannot play a wav file

**code to list the content of a directory**

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash","-c","ls"});
                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                        String line=null;
                        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                        int exitVal = p.waitFor();
                        System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);
```

**code to play a wav file, this doesn't work**

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/usr/bin/aplay","~/javafx/examples/PrayerTime/dist/police_s.wav"});
                            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                            String line=null;
                            while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                                System.out.println(line);
                            }
                            int exitVal = p.waitFor();
                            System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);
```

**I get the following error**

```
Exited with error code 1
```

Comment: so you got no error rather than `Exited with error code 1`?

Comment: when the comman succedded in the directory listing example i got error code 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slight variation of the code seen in the [info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for the [javasound](/questions/tagged/javasound) tag.

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class LoopSound {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(
            "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
            getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

It works from the command line.

Comment: excelent, how can i play a local file mate :)

Comment: URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("gameover.wav");

Comment: I am usin eiher of these but not working any idea, File soundFile = new File("~/javafx/examples/PrayerTime/dist/police_s.wav");
                        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("police_s.wav");

Comment: ok here it is,,, pfffff  URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Audio/police_s.wav");

Comment: Great example. `Thread.sleep(5000);` is what I was missing in my code. Why is this needed? What does this do exactly? And how do I make it so that the milliseconds always match up with the length of the actual clip?

Comment: To add to the information, it might be a good idea to use `Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);` instead of just `Thread.sleep(5000);` so that it will always play the exact length of the audio.

Comment: @tazboy With `Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY` the clip length becomes irrelevant, since that will play 'forever'.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I forgot to mention to remove that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a system error code which comes after executing any command on cmd/terminal. Exit codes like 1 - 2, 126 - 165, and 255 have special meanings, and should therefore be avoided for user-specified exit parameters.many scripts use an exit 1 as a general bailout upon error. Since exit code 1 signifies so many possible errors, this probably would not be helpful in debugging.
There has been an attempt to systematize exit status numbers (see /usr/include/sysexits.h), but this is intended for C and C++ programmers. A similar standard for scripting might be appropriate.
[Here you can find some system error codes](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/exitcodes.html)

Comment: I gave the xample of listing a directory, which worked, and then wanted to modify this example to be able to play a wav file. can you help me with this